# Accessing real frame buffer of PCI card

Tags: linux-device-driver, intel, framebuffer, pci, pci-e

I am trying to access the framebuffer on my systems VGA controller card.

**lscpi -vn** gives:

```
00:02.0 0300: 8086:2a02 (rev 0c) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: 1028:022f
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 45
    Memory at fea00000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
    Memory at e0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    I/O ports at eff8 [size=8]
    Expansion ROM at <unassigned> [disabled]
    Capabilities: [90] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [d0] Power Management version 3
    Kernel driver in use: i915
```

Now, I access the device and I get:

```
fb_base = pci_resource_start( devp, 0 ); **output: FEA00000**
fb_size = pci_resource_len( devp, 0 );   **output: 1MB**
```

So the range of framebuffer is `FEA00000 - FEB00000`

But from the lspci -vn output This region is non prefetchable.

Does that mean I am not pointing to the frame buffer at all.

```
Is my framebuffer at address E0000000:
```

1. The driver currently using the resource is the Intel i915
2. So maybe when I request region or IRQ it can clash if not shared by that driver.
3. If I remove the i915 rmmod it to insmod my driver, will my screen go blank.

Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: You have two regions of memory in PCI configuration space. If you want to get resource from BAR1 you have to specify the BAR index in the calls.

Comment: @AndyShevchenko the above code accesses BAR0 I changed it to access BAR1 - > pci_resource_start( devp, 1); and I get no result. There is nothing in BAR1

Comment: /* Before gen4, the registers and the GTT are behind different BARs. However, from gen4 onwards, the registers and the GTT are shared in the same BAR, so we want to restrict this ioremap from clobbering the GTT which we want ioremap_wc instead. Fortunately, the register BAR remains the same size for all the earlier generations up to Ironlake. */

Comment: Can you please summarize that and format it pertaining to my question. I will definitely read about what you have written but first I need to develop confidence.

Comment: It was just a comment from the i915 driver. I suggest you to look at it.